# can't find element by xpath using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I try this xpath but I don't know how to continue ?
i have 2 objects in popup menu and i want to select the first one

the html of the page is:

```
</div>
<input class="sprite form-enter" type="submit" value="" name="wobi">
</div>
<div class="container">
<img src="/_media/home/img/icons/pension.png">
<div class="login-text-container">
<a class="sprite form-enter" href="https://pension.wobi.co.il/login" value="" name="pension" type="submit"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

the java code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='sprite form-enter' and input//@name='wobi']")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

After execution of code I got the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='sprite form-enter' and input/@name='wobi']"}

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Do you mean you have two element with the same class `sprite form-enter` and name `wobi`??

Comment: your XPath is wrong better try and check if it works in Firebug / Firepath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are try with wrong `xpath`, the correct `xpath` would be :-

```
//input[@class='sprite form-enter' and @name='wobi']
```

But I would suggest you, try using `By.cssSelector()` here because it would be much faster than `xpath` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.sprite.form-enter[name = 'wobi']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this selector:

```
//input[@class='sprite form-enter'][@name='wobi']
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a compound class, try using `CSSSelector`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sprite.form-enter")).click();
```